# What will be the output of the following C code?

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *m() {
    int *p = 5;
    return p;
}

void main() {
    int *k = m();
    printf("%d", k);
}
```

The answer is coming `5`.
Can someone explain how the answer is coming `5`?
I have tried to solve it but couldn't understand how it works.

Comment: function `m` returns a pointer to address 5, which you then print. BTW, you are printing `int*` as `int`, which is "not so good" sort to speak. Better use `%p` there.

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: @EOF: I'm pretty sure that `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(int*)` by the language standard, so that print is guaranteed not to crash the program (no memory access violation under any circumstances). That said, it could lead to different behavior depending on the endianess of the platform.

Comment: There are **only four** lines of code. You could probably afford to tell us which ones you _do_ understand, if any.

Comment: @goodvibration Printing a pointer using `%d` is ...

Comment: @4386427: read the comments above!

Comment: @goodvibration No comment can change that `%d` for pointers are just wrong.

Comment: @goodvibration The `printf()` is *absolutely* undefined behavior. C11 draft standard n1570: *7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function [...] 8
The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
d,i
The int argument [...] 9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is
not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
undefined.* and *7.21.6.3 The printf function [...] 2
The printf function is equivalent to fprintf with the argument stdout interposed
before the arguments to printf.*

Comment: It also asks one question in the title, a different one in the body, and doesn't display any effort. I don't see any downvotes as I'm writing this anyway, but I don't think UB wolves would be the only plausible explanation for any that do turn up.

Comment: @4386427 No downvote can change that *this is a Q&A site* and not everybody fully understands whatʼs UB.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined. A downvote can be given to a question that is not useful.

Comment: That said I agree with Useless about this not being a good question: what does OP not understand, what *does* OP understand, what result would be expected?

Comment: You can nevertheless explain to this user the likely reason for the output on his/her given platform, then carry on explaining **why** it is undefined behavior for any platform in general, with the term *why* being the key difference between science and religion. Ahhh nevermind that, who am I trying to persuade anyway.... given up on this website long time ago...

Comment: @DanielH I have not made any comments about downvotes so you must be addressing the wrong user

Comment: @goodvibration You can but that would be pure guessing as we don't know anything about OPs system

Comment: @4386427 Somehow not all the comments were loaded; I only saw goodvibrationʼs comment about “no need to give a 'dislike' vote” and not the one about it not necessarily being UB, and thought you were responding to that.

Comment: @4386427: You don't need to, you can explain, for example, that if the sizes of `int` and `int*` are both 4 bytes, then the value on the stack when `printf` is called will be `0x00000005`. You can also provide a similar explanation for the case when the size of `int*` is 8 bytes AND the platform is Little-Endian. Then you can continue to explain why it is not guaranteed to give the same result on every platform, and if you really wanna be thorough, then give an example when `sizeof(int*) < sizeof(int)`, which would lead to accessing undetermined memory.

Comment: @goodvibration clearly you do not understand what undefined behaviour is then.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Don't forget to carry your daily prayer to the goddess of UB.

Comment: @goodvibration When answering a pure C question without any other references (e.g. to a specific system) there is only one place to get the answer: The C standard. If the C standard says it's UB, the case is closed. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @4386427: see the comment above yours.

Answer (score 1):

There is one UB here as you use wrong printf format.

If you explicitly convert it to `int` the code will be 100% fine, but if pointer and integer have different sizes not every value of the pointer will be correctly converted.

You need also to cast integer to the pointer to suppress the warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *m()
{
    int *p = (int *)5;   // conversion of the integer 5 to the pointer
    return p;
}

int main(void)
{
    int *k = m();
    printf("%d", (int)k);  // conversion of the pointers (keeping the
           // converted integer value of 5) back to the integer value.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, they won't be fine, the conversion of an integer to pointer is implementation defined and even undefined if the integer was not derived originally from a pointer, or doesn't point to an object and/or not suitably aligned.

Comment: Alignment does not anything here. The pointer is not used.

Comment: It does not matter, the C standard says that the behaviour is undefined if a value is cast to a pointer type and the pointer is not suitably aligned for the targeted type. For example if you latter do cast it to an `int` again and check its LSB bit using `& 1`,  a C compiler can hardcode that to 0.

Comment: Also `void main()` -> `int main()`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala theretically yes but I do not know any implementation where it is really an UB.

Comment: @chqrlie true //

Comment: @AnttiHaapala *Where* does that c standard say that converting an integer to a pointer is undefined if the value of the integer corresponds to an unaligned pointer value? C11 draft standard n1570 only explicitly mentions that creating an unaligned pointer by conversion is undefined behavior when converting between pointer types: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.3 Conversions 6.3.2.3 Pointers*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala it is a nonsense exmaple as compiler knows how the code is aligned. https://godbolt.org/z/YW3YjG

Comment: @AnttiHaapala and here you can test how the code is aligned :) https://godbolt.org/z/n7nPKE

Comment: @P__J__ oops :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala still no UB example ..... except the one ehere pointer value cannot be represented by integer and vice versa (because of the size differences)

Comment: It is UB in itself if you read the standard. The reason why it even exists in the first place is because the char * => int * can have a different representation, and there might not even exist unaligned pointers.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I don see it in the standard stating that converting to and from without use or converting pointer to another pointer is an UB. IMO it is your over-interpretation of the standard.

Comment: "5 An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.67)"

Comment: @AnttiHaapala still no UB. ID yes but not UB

Comment: This answer does not answer the question: “What will be the output of the following C code?”